# Facebook SDK LoginManager.getInstance() returning null

Tags: android, facebook

Has anybody found a solution to `LoginManager.getInstance()` returning null

See `AndroidMainfest.xml code below:

```
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/fb_api_id"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

See `MainActivity` code below:

- `OnCreate`

  ```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle 
      persistentState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

              FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

              LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
                      , new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                  @Override
                  public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {

                      GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                          @Override
                          public void onCompleted(final JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                              if (user != null) {
                                  // handle user details
                              } else {
                                  // handle user being null
                              }
                          }
                      });

                      request.executeAsync();
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onCancel() {
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                      // handle error
                  }
              });

          }
  ```

  - `OnActivityResult`

    ```
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    ```

See `LoginFragment` code below:

- `OnClickListener`

  ```
  @OnClick(R.id.loginFacebookButton)
      public void onFacebookLoginButtonClick() {
          LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(getActivity(), Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));
      }
  ```

Lastly see `LogCat` output below:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    null
            at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:99)
            at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.<init>(LoginManager.java:70)
            at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.getInstance(LoginManager.java:81)
            at LoginFragment.onFacebookLoginButtonClick(LoginFragment.java:118)
            at LoginFragment$$ViewInjector$5.doClick(LoginFragment$$ViewInjector.java:53)
            at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
            at android.widget.Button.performClick(Button.java:148)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18395)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

See reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3

EDITED

This has been resolved and is due to overriding `default` ssl for `okHttp`

Find a link to solution here:
https://bitbucket.org/byteorbit/splitbill-standardbank-android/commits/97e196b859706a3658a7dc00143e5890bbe2da11

Comment: what version of android is this happening on?

Comment: all versions I have worked with so far, however the problem is solved, however I did not solve it, I do recall hearing something to do with overriding the default ssl for okhttp.

Comment: Here is a link to the solution: https://bitbucket.org/byteorbit/splitbill-standardbank-android/commits/97e196b859706a3658a7dc00143e5890bbe2da11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that resolved this error and it is to do with overriding default ssl for okHttp.

Find a link to solution here: https://bitbucket.org/byteorbit/splitbill-standardbank-android/commits/97e196b859706a3658a7dc00143e5890bbe2da11

Comment: I don't have permission to access that solution, would it be possible to post a mirror?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not however you may look at the `okio` 143 fix: https://github.com/square/okio/pull/143